# Почему не работают слоты в загруженной форме через QUiLoader?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Не хотят работать слоты в загруженой форме через QUiLoader. Вот конструктор базового класса:

```
LoaderWidget::LoaderWidget(const QString &nwgt, QWidget * p):
    QWidget(p)
{
    std::shared_ptr<QUiLoader> pUIl (new QUiLoader);
    QFile ui("/home/userc/authAstra/widgets/" + nwgt + ".ui");
    if(ui.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        m_widget = pUIl.get()->load(&ui);
    if(ui.isOpen()) ui.close();
}
```

Вот дочерний

```
AuthWidget::AuthWidget(QWidget * parent)
    :LoaderWidget("auth", parent),
     local_auth_handle(NULL)
{
    ui_loginBtn = m_widget->findChild<QPushButton*>("btnLogIn");

    connect(ui_loginBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(slot_authenticate_system()));
}
```

слот объявлен как public slots, connect не ругается, просто не работает вообще. Хотя код

```
connect(ui_loginBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

выполняется. Макрос Q_OBJECT есть. Не пойму, почему.

Comment: Возможно, я чего то не понимаю, но строка `connect(ui_loginBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(slot_authenticate_system()));` не должна компилироваться.

Comment: ...потомучто...

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов, коннект с макросами SIGNAL и SLOT для компилятора нормальным будет, а проблемы с неправильным подключением будет замечен в рантайме

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(ui_loginBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(slot_authenticate_system()));
```

Такая запись коненкта эквивалентна следующему

```
connect(ui_loginBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(slot_authenticate_system()));
```

Т.е. сигнал кнопки будет искать слот `slot_authenticate_system` в объекте `AuthWidget`. Если вам надо слать сигнал другому объекту, то указывайте явно. Из контекста вопроса непонятно, что такое `qAuth`

Comment: пардон, там qApp